# Bash script assignment and comparison

Tags: bash

i run this script from the command line:

```
check_databse_exist=`mysql -u root --password=root -Bse 'show databases' | egrep -v 'information_schema|mysql'`
for db in $check_databse_exist; do
if [ "$db" == "test_traffic" ] ; then
   exist=1
fi
done

if [ $exist -eq 1 ] ; then
   #do other stuff
fi

exit 0
```

why is it giving:

```
 [: 16: jobeet: unexpected operator
 [: 16: jobeet_test: unexpected operator
 [: 16: landpage_db: unexpected operator
 [: 16: my_db: unexpected operator
 [: 16: symfony2: unexpected operator
 ./cibuild: 24: [0: not found
```

i just want to loop and if found set exist = 1
thanks

Comment: try to remove all whitespaces around = and ==

Comment: Please don't edit your question iteratively, so that the former helpful answers look silly. In rare cases add more information transparently, and else start a new question, if you have a new question. Your title and tags should reflect your problem precisely, and the upvoted and accepted answers shall fit to your question, and you can only accept one question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if [$exist == 1] ; then
```

Due to a shell scripting quirk you need spaces around the square brackets. They're not optional.

```
if [ $exist == 1 ]; then
```

For what it's worth, you could refactor this a bit if you merely want to check for the existence of one table, and don't otherwise need `$check_databse_exist`. The idea would be to to replace the for loop with a grep.

```
if mysql -u root --password=root -Bse 'show databases' | grep -qw test_traffic; then
    # Database exists.
fi
```

`grep -q` produces no output, it merely returns success or failure. `grep -w` is optional but a good practice; it prevents a table like `test_traffic2` from matching.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
check_databse_exist=`mysql -u root --password=root -Bse 'show databases' | egrep -v 'information_schema|mysql'`
for db in $check_databse_exist; do
  if [ "$db" == "test_traffic" ] ; then
    exist=1
fi
done

if [ $exist -eq 1 ] ; then
   #do other stuff
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: thanks i edited my main post (pls see main post )but still get the  [: 16: jobeet: unexpected operator
 [: 16: jobeet_test: unexpected operator
 [: 16: landpage_db: unexpected operator
 [: 16: my_db: unexpected operator
 [: 16: symfony2: unexpected operator errors???

Comment: It seems like you still have some space missing. The test command assumes your database names to be operators...

Comment: thanks but i opted for the inline if mysql -u root --password=root -Bse 'show databases' | grep -qw test_traffic; :)